# Chrome extension to hide all tabs but the currently active one?

Tags: chrome

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension to hide all tabs temporarily except for the currently active and opened one.

I found extensions like [PanicButton](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panicbutton/faminaibgiklngmfpfbhmokfmnglamcm) but those I have identified do hide all tabs, including the currently active one.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Clear Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-tabs/leopnacgjdikhakdignjfelidbbalbcc?hl=en)? It works as you want it, but only if you have all your tabs open in one window.

Comment: I would have to extract the active tab into a new window for this to work.